# Height and width of complete webpage

Tags: javascript, dom, html

I am trying to get the height and width of complete webpage regardless of the viewport.

That is, even if the browser is not maximized, I need to know what the complete size of the webpage is.

Methods I have looked at include document.body.clientWidth/clientHeight, innerHeight/Width etc. But they all change when the browser is made smaller.

Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**--EDIT--** I think I have a better idea of what you want. Check out the [`scrollHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight) and [`scrollWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollWidth) properties.

```js
document.getElementById('width').innerHTML = document.body.scrollWidth;
document.getElementById('height').innerHTML = document.body.scrollHeight;
```

```html
scroll width is: <div id="width"></div>
scroll height is: <div id="height"></div>
```

---

Check out the properties for the [`screen`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/screen) object.

**`availHeight` and `availWidth` return the screen height and width in pixels that are available to the window (excluding interface features such as the taskbar).**

These values do not change even if you resize the window of your browser. Try out the snippet below:

```js
document.getElementById('width').innerHTML = screen.availWidth;
document.getElementById('height').innerHTML = screen.availHeight;
```

```html
width is: <div id="width"></div>
height is: <div id="height"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I am completely new to this domain, but using screen.width gives me a larger value than getComputedStyle(document.body).width, unsure why. Also, since I will be using this javascript from the context of a webextension, I am a little unsure how I can get a handle of the screen object. thanks

Comment: It's bigger because as you said in your question: "I am trying to get the height and width of complete webpage regardless of the viewport."

Comment: @puzzledchamp Can you perhaps clarify your use case? I note the answers do different things.

Comment: @jdphenix: I am trying to get the total area of the webpage, irrespective of the whether the browser is maximised or not. I need it because I want to find the percent of space taken by advertisements in a webpage. Hence,getting the correct values of areas of ads and area of entire webpage is important. Pls let me know whats the best way

Comment: @jdphenix: Also wanted to add that this javascript will be running in the context of an extension on a remote box. This remote machine is the one opening the web browser, and I have no access to it. Hence, I cant even maximize it, which is why i need to get the correct size of the webpage irrespective of whether the browser is maximized or not

Comment: `screen.availWidth` and `screen.availHeight` from my answer get you the amount of space in pixels available to the window, so even if you change the size of the browser, the values will not change.

Comment: @boombox: But isnt screen giving the size of my screen? it is always fixed at 1366*768. I however want the whole area of the webpage, whatever is visible and whatever is NOT visible now but will be visible by scrolling.

Comment: @puzzledchamp ahhh that makes a lot more sense! sorry about that. I updated my answer. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `getComputedStyle()`. It returns an object which you can query the `width` and `height` properties.

```
getComputedStyle(document.body).width;
```

Of note, if a page has a layout which changes with the viewport size, the result of this call *will change*. However, if the client becomes so small as to need to scroll, the returned result still be the actual width of the `<body>`.

> Methods I have looked at include document.body.clientWidth/clientHeight, innerHeight/Width etc. But they all change when the browser is made smaller.

And the reason this is true is because the window size is mutable and layouts will change based upon the window size.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I was trying it out on a few random websites and I noticed that in certain cases the body may be smaller than actual visible space. For example, I opened a website where the body was 1349*155 but a div inside it was 1349*6672. What should be done in such cases?

Comment: Walk through the DOM and find the largest element? That still may not be perfect though.

Comment: Hi @jdphenix, just noticed that for this website, http://www.geekpedia.com/KB71_How-to-maximize-the-browser-window-using-JavaScript.html, 
even though there is scrolling space, getComputedStyle(document.body).width;  is still returning only the viewport space. How to workaround this?